# Azure And Silverlight: Error - Could not download silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, azure

I am trying to get started with Azure so that we can port an existing Silverlight app to Azure.

**Problem:** On running the Windows Azure project that contains Silverlight web app in web role, a blank page is displayed in browser due to error 2104: Could not download Silverlight application. Check web server settings

**Things that I have tried**

.xap mime type is registered for the Default Web Site in IIS7. Even the applicationHost.config file contains the right entries.

I have restarted the storage and compute emulators and performed IIS reset.

I also tried to put the following code in the silverlight app web.config

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".xap" mimeType="application/x-silverlight-app" />
    </staticContent>
```

But this caused a compile error. Something tot he effect of not being able to attach the debugger to iis worker...

Any ideas how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Got the Problem. I had set the Mime type on the "Default Web Site". I needed to set it on the IIS Server (The topmost item in  the tree).

It works now.